# i have problem this library react-native-ble-plx. Error is Operation was rejected

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ble-plx

I try to connect my React Native app with a generic smartwatch, but I can't.

When I execute this code:

```
    bleManager.readCharacteristicForDevice(
                    device,
                    heartRateService.uuid,
                    heartRateCharacteristic.uuid
                  )
```

I catch this error: '**Operation was rejected**'.

The UUID for service is `0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb` corresponding to heart rate and Characteristic is `00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`. For several service and Characteristic, I can obtain the real values but for others for example that case I have problems obtaining values. Also, I search for the error code in the library and obtain: "**Native module couldn't start operation due to internal state, which doesn't allow to do that.**"